# In The Crew, if I do not have a color, do I have to play a rocket?

Tags: untagged

The Crew – Quest for Planet Nine is a trick taking game where cards can be number of colors or rockets acting as trumps.

If in my hand, I do not have the requested color but I do have a rocket, do I have to play it or can I play anything from my hand ?

*Going through the rules, it does not seem to tell that the rocket must be played but as this principle is in most trick taking games I know of, I'd like a confirmation.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the rules [here](https://www.ultraboardgames.com/the-crew/game-rules.php) it says (emphasis mine).

> There are five card suits: pink, blue, green, yellow, and rocket
> cards. Following suit means that each player must "follow" the suit
> choice of the first player; i.e., you have to play a card of the same
> type. Only if you do not have a card of this suit **may** you play a card
> of a different suit.

and later is says (emphasis mine)

> During a color-suited trick, a rocket **may** only be played if a card
> in the color suit cannot be played.

Reading this sounds like it follows expected playing of trick taking is option.  If you can not follow suit you **may** play a card of a different suit.  You **may** only play a rocket if you can't follow suit.

Neither of these situations say **must** so if you can't follow suit and have the choice of playing a rocket card or not that is a free choice.

Answer (score 4):

The [rules](https://www.ultraboardgames.com/the-crew/game-rules.php) expressly say you are never forced to play a specific card:

> During a trick, **there is no mandate to play a specific card**. If you have multiple cards that you can play, you may play a low card, even though you would have been able to win the trick with a higher card. In other words, you are not forced to win the trick.

Comment: Thanks for this additional extract of the rules. I had (badly) interpreted that part as if it was only about numbers in a given color and not about rockets as well.

Comment: Of course, if you have only one card of the lead suit, you have to play it